# faster implementation of sum ( for Codility test )

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, optimization

How can the following simple implementation of `sum` be faster?

```
private long sum( int [] a, int begin, int end ) {
    if( a == null   ) {
        return 0;
    }
    long r = 0;
    for( int i =  begin ; i < end ; i++ ) {
       r+= a[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

**EDIT**

Background is in order.

Reading latest entry on coding horror, I came to this site: http://codility.com which has this interesting programming test.

Anyway, I got 60 out of 100 in my submission, and basically ( I think ) is because this implementation of sum, because those parts where I failed are the performance parts. I'm getting TIME_OUT_ERROR's

So, I was wondering if an optimization in the algorithm is possible.

So, no built in functions or assembly would be allowed. This my be done in C, C++, C#, Java or pretty much in any other.

**EDIT**

As usual, mmyers was right. I did profile the code and I saw most of the time was spent on that function, but I didn't understand why. So what I did was to throw away my implementation and start with a new one.

This time I've got an optimal solution [ according to [San Jacinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124493/san-jacinto) O(n) -see comments to MSN below - ]

This time I've got 81% on Codility which I think is good enough. The problem is that I didn't take the 30 mins. but around 2 hrs. but I guess that leaves me still as a good programmer, for I could work on the problem until I found an optimal solution:

Here's my result.

[image: my result on codility]

I never understood what is those "combinations of..." nor how to test "extreme_first"

Comment: Do you allow inline assembly in C++?

Comment: No one can comment on speed unless you explain what language and platform you are using. Like mmyers says, if this is c++ you could inline some assembly. If it's C# the inbuilt Enumerable.Sum() method might be faster, who knows. I'm sure Java has it's own tricks too.

Comment: @mmyers: Not that much. Most likely in the optimization is on the algorithm part rather than in the implementation part :-/ ( if that even makes sense )

Comment: @Oscar: If assembly is allowed, depending on the target platform, SSE vector instructions could be used to parallelize it.

Comment: Unless you want to split the task into `NUM_CORES` threads for arrays of a size great enough to benefit despite the overhead in thread initialization, I think you're pretty much done.

Comment: By the way, when you say "basically ( I think ) is because this implementation of sum", you really mean "I profiled it and found that it's spending 40% of its time in this implementation of sum", right? Because otherwise, this is a fairly pointless exercise. :)

Comment: I also could not come up with O(n) solution in 30 minutes. So I definitely need to improve. I came up with O(n ^2) solution in like 5 mins. We have to remember one thing, if you are writing LOB applications, it's okie if your solution is O(n^2) if n is small and time to deliver is more important.

Comment: I have one in O(n), but I didn't check all the edge cases and I didn't use longs. I only got a 50. :P (But I used less than half the allotted time, so at least in theory I could have fixed all those problems.)

Comment: This is a perfect example of why people need to profile. Just like people around here always say, what you think is the choke point often isn't. You simply don't know until you measure.

Comment: @Evan, you don't need to profile if you know what you are doing. This will transform this conversation into flag waving, but it took me 30 seconds to figure out why this might be slow (O(n^2)) and how to make it O(n).

Although I guess that would mean profile if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: This is how I profiled ( with out a profiler btw )  I make a 2 thread version of the `sum`
 method and I saw it took about the same time.  I added print logs and saw I was creating up to 2k threads ( not at the same time ) for my 1k array.   That's when I knew I was calling the method `sum` too many times. What lead me to that conclusion ( I'm not as clever as MSN and it take me more than 30 seconds ) was the test failing in large sets. Otherwise I wouldn't go that far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think your problem is with the function that's summing the array, it's probably that you're summing the array WAY to frequently. If you simply sum the WHOLE array once, and then step through the array until you find the first equilibrium point you should decrease the execution time sufficiently.

```
int equi ( int[] A ) {
    int equi = -1;

    long lower = 0;
    long upper = 0;
    foreach (int i in A)
        upper += i;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        upper -= A[i];
        if (upper == lower)
        {
            equi = i;
            break;
        }
        else
            lower += A[i];
    }

    return equi;
}
```

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly what I did. Initially I've had was: `if(sum(0,i) == sum(i,end)) return i` but that invoked too many time to `sum` so I change it for: `total = sum(a)` and inside the for: `if( current == total-current ) { return i } `

Comment: changes to int equi = -1; instead of 0 and you'll get a 100/100 with this solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Here is my solution and I scored 100%**

```
 public static int solution(int[] A)
    {
        double sum = A.Sum(d => (double)d);
        double leftSum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++){
            if (leftSum == (sum-leftSum-A[i])) {
                return i;
            }
            else {
                leftSum = leftSum + A[i];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Requires System.Linq; but nice answer!

Comment: I liked this solution but I don't think worst-case time complexity is O(N) first  double sum = A.Sum(d => (double)d); is O(N) then you have one more for which make it O(2N), am I right ?

Comment: @TarekAboELkheir O(2N) = O(N). That's how Big Oh works.

Comment: This solution is 100% correct yet it bothers me with the style xD . What's the point of `else` here? `if(leftSum == sum-leftSum-A[i]) return i;  leftSum+=A[i]` is enough :p

Answer (score 5):

This code is simple enough that unless `a` is *quite* small, it's probably going to be limited primarily by memory bandwidth. As such, you probably can't hope for any significant gain by working on the summing part itself (e.g., unrolling the loop, counting down instead of up, executing sums in parallel -- unless they're on separate CPUs, each with its own access to memory). The biggest gain will probably come from issuing some preload instructions so most of the data will already be in the cache by the time you need it. The rest will just (at best) get the CPU to hurry up more, so it waits longer.

Edit: It appears that most of what's above has little to do with the real question. It's kind of small, so it may be difficult to read, but, I tried just using `std::accumulate()` for the initial addition, and it seemed to think that was all right:

[image: Codility Results]

Comment: Probably true as the integer units on most processors are so fast now that even SIMD instructions don't do much unless you're crunching a lot of numbers.  I suspect the possible pipeline stalls from poorly ordered SSE instructions would slow down the SIMD version enough that it wouldn't offer much speed over the naive solution.

Comment: +1.  In D they have vectorized array ops that use SSE instructions.  They're nice syntactic sugar, but not any faster than using a plain old loop except for very small arrays.

Answer (score 5):

If this is based on the actual sample problem, your issue isn't the sum. Your issue is how you calculate the equilibrium index. A naive implementation is O(n^2). An optimal solution is much much better.

Comment: An optimal solution is O(n), as you say. Since the sample is written/tested online, i seriously doubt that it is testing the minutia of pipelining and loop unrolling.

Comment: @San, even then this would be dominated by memory accesses as you scale up. :)

Comment: MSN, any ideas on an implmentation which is not O(n^2)

Comment: @Solution Yogi: I did it :P ( not knowing exactly how, but I did :P )   I did what I do for work, if I have a working solution and is taking too long, I tweak the solution to yield the same result with different steps and it worked! :)

Comment: Oscar, I was so bugged that I could not solve it in O(n). Thinking more about it, finally I also found a way to solve it in O(n). It is satisfying to come up with a solution! :)

Answer (score 4):

Some tips:

- Use a profiler to identify where you're spending a lot of time.
- Write good performance tests so that you can tell the exact effect of every single change you make.  Keep careful notes.
- If it turns out that the bottleneck is the checks to ensure that you're dereferencing a legal address inside the array, and you can guarantee that begin and end are in fact both inside the array, then consider fixing the array, making a pointer to the array, and doing the algorithm in pointers rather than arrays.  Pointers are unsafe; they do not spend any time checking to make sure you're still inside the array, so therefore they can be somewhat faster. But *you* take responsibility then for ensuring that you do not corrupt every byte of memory in the address space.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the problem is in the code you provided, but somehow the bigger solution must be suboptimal. This code looks good for calculating the sum of one slice of the array, but maybe it's not what you need to solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the fastest you could get would be to have your int array 16-byte aligned, stream 32 bytes into two `__m128i` variables (VC++) and call `_mm_add_epi32` (again, a VC++ intrinsic) on the chunks. Reuse one of the chunks to keep adding into it and on the final chunk extract your four ints and add them the old fashioned way.

The bigger question is why simple addition is a worthy candidate for optimization.

Edit: I see it's mostly an academic exercise.  Perhaps I'll give it a go tomorrow and post some results...

Answer (score 1):

In C# 3.0, **my** computer and **my** OS this is faster as long as you can guarantee that 4 consecutive numbers won't overflow the range of an int, probably because most additions are done using 32-bit math.
However using a better algorithm usually provides higher speed up than any micro-optimization.

Time for a 100 millon elements array:

4999912596452418 -> 233ms (sum)

4999912596452418 -> 126ms (sum2)

```
    private static long sum2(int[] a, int begin, int end)
    {
        if (a == null) { return 0; }
        long r = 0;
        int i = begin;
        for (; i < end - 3; i+=4)
        {
            //int t = ;
            r += a[i] + a[i + 1] + a[i + 2] + a[i + 3];
        }
        for (; i < end; i++) { r += a[i]; }
        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you with an O(n^2) algorithm, but you can optimize your sum.

At a previous company, we had Intel come by and give us optimization tips.  They had one non-obvious and somewhat cool trick.  Replace:

```
long r = 0; 
for( int i =  begin ; i < end ; i++ ) { 
   r+= a[i]; 
}
```

with

```
long r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0, r4 = 0; 
for( int i =  begin ; i < end ; i+=4 ) { 
   r1+= a[i];
   r2+= a[i + 1];
   r3+= a[i + 2];
   r4+= a[i + 3];
}
long r = r1 + r2 + r3 + r4;
// Note: need to be clever if array isn't divisible by 4
```

Why this is faster:
  In the original implementation, your variable r is a bottleneck.  Every time through the loop, you have to pull data from memory array a (which takes a couple cycles), but you can't do multiple pulls in parallel, because the value of r in the next iteration of the loop depends on the value of r in this iteration of the loop.  In the second version, r1, r2, r3, and r4 are independent, so the processor can hyperthread their execution.  Only at the very end do they come together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thought:

```
private static ArrayList equi(int[] A)
{
    ArrayList answer = new ArrayList();

    //if(A == null) return -1; 
    if ((answer.Count == null))
    {
        answer.Add(-1);
        return answer;
    }

    long sum0 = 0, sum1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++) sum0 += A[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        sum0 -= A[i];
        if (i > 0) { sum1 += A[i - 1]; }
        if (sum1 == sum0) answer.Add(i);
    //return i;
    }
    //return -1;
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the following:

```
int* a1 = a + begin;
for( int i = end - begin - 1; i >= 0 ; i-- )
{
    r+= a1[i];
}
```

might be faster.
The advantage is that we compare against zero in the loop.

Of course, with a **really** good optimizer there should be no difference at all.

Another possibility would be

```
int* a2 = a + end - 1;
for( int i = -(end - begin - 1); i <= 0 ; i++ )
{
    r+= a2[i];
}
```

here we traversing the items in the same order, just not comparing to `end`.

Comment: Depending on the processor and cache, this might actually be slower. Fewer instructions does not always equal more speed.

Comment: @mmyers: what actually can be slower here? we are traversing the same items, just backwards.

Comment: Prefetchers often assume that memory accesses will be sequential. I don't have time (or sufficiently advanced knowledge) to elaborate, but I think it's a Googleable concept.

Comment: @mmyers: ok, look at the second example

Comment: I would be surprised if these make any difference at all

Comment: (Also for Java, HotSpot doesn't bother doing a load of optimisations for backwards loops because sane people don't write them (for one reason HotSpot is quite smart about forward loops).)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C or C++ and develop for modern desktop systems and are willing to learn some assembler or learn about GCC intrinsics, you could use [SIMD instructions](http://courses.ece.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/inst-ref-simd.html).

[This library](http://volnitsky.com/project/lvvlib/array/) is an example of what is possible for `float` and `double` arrays, similar results should be possible for integer arithmetic since SSE has integer instructions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same naive implementation and here's my O(n) solution. I did not use the IEnumerable Sum method because it was not available at Codility. My solution still doesn't check for overflow in case the input has large numbers so it's failing that particular test on Codility.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new[] {-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0};
            Console.WriteLine(equi(list));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int equi(int[] A)
        {
            if (A == null || A.Length == 0)
                return -1;

            if (A.Length == 1)
                return 0;

            var upperBoundSum = GetTotal(A);
            var lowerBoundSum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                lowerBoundSum += (i - 1) >= 0 ? A[i - 1] : 0;
                upperBoundSum -= A[i];
                if (lowerBoundSum == upperBoundSum)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private static int GetTotal(int[] ints)
        {
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i=0; i < ints.Length; i++)
                sum += ints[i];
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Codility Results]

Comment: +1 Great!!!... What's that "combinations_of_two" all about? About the "extreme_lange_numbers" is **very very** easy, just use `long` in the `GetTotal` method instead of `int` and you'll have 100% ;)

Comment: I don't know what those cases are about. But I do some initial checks e.g. If Array Length is zero or 1, the code returns equilibrium index right away. May be that's why my average timing is 0.072s where as your average timing is 0.244s. It was a fun exercise, thank you for brining it up! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int equi ( int[] A ) {
    if (A == null || A.length == 0)
     return -1;
 long tot = 0;
 int len = A.length;
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
     tot += A[i];
 if(tot == 0)
     return (len-1);
 long partTot = 0;
 for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
 {
  partTot += A[i];
  if(partTot*2+A[i+1] == tot)
   return i+1;
 }
 return -1;
```

}

I considered the array as a bilance so if the equilibrium index exist then half of the weight is on the left. So I only compare the partTot (partial total) x 2 with the total weight of the array. 
the Alg takes O(n) + O(n)

Answer (score 0):

**100% O(n) solution in C**

```
int equi ( int A[], int n ) {

    long long sumLeft = 0;
    long long sumRight = 0;
    int i;

    if (n <= 0) return -1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        sumRight += A[i];
    i = 0;

    do {
        if (sumLeft == sumRight)
            return i;

        sumLeft += A[i];

        if ((i+1) < n)
            sumRight -= A[i+1];
        i++;
    } while (i < n);

    return -1;
}
```

Probably not perfect but it passes their tests anyway :)

Can't say I'm a big fan of Codility though - it is an interesting idea, but I found the requirements a little too vague.  I think I'd be more impressed if they gave you requirements + a suite of unit tests that test those requirements and *then* asked you to write code. That's how most TDD happens anyway. I don't think doing it blind really gains anything other than allowing them to throw in some corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

100% correctness and performance of this code is tested

```js
Private Function equi(ByVal A() As Integer) As Integer
        Dim index As Integer = -1
        If A.Length > 0 And Not IsDBNull(A) Then
            Dim sumLeft As Long = 0
            Dim sumRight As Long = ArraySum(A)
            For i As Integer = 0 To A.Length - 1
                Dim val As Integer = A(i)

                sumRight -= val
                If sumLeft = sumRight Then
                    index = i
                End If
                sumLeft += val
            Next
        End If

        Return index
    End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Just some thought, not sure if accessing the pointer directly be faster

```
    int* pStart = a + begin;
    int* pEnd = a + end;
    while (pStart != pEnd)
    {
        r += *pStart++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{In Pascal + Assembly}
{$ASMMODE INTEL}
function equi (A : Array of longint; n : longint ) : longint;
var c:Longint;
    label noOverflow1;
    label noOverflow2;
    label ciclo;
    label fine;
    label Over;
    label tot;
Begin
 Asm
    DEC n
    JS over
    XOR ECX, ECX   {Somma1}
    XOR EDI, EDI   {Somma2}
    XOR EAX, EAX
    MOV c, EDI
    MOV ESI, n
  tot:
    MOV EDX, A
    MOV EDX, [EDX+ESI*4]
    PUSH EDX
    ADD ECX, EDX
    JNO nooverflow1
    ADD c, ECX
    nooverflow1:
    DEC ESI
  JNS tot;
    SUB ECX, c
    SUB EDI, c
  ciclo:
    POP EDX
    SUB ECX, EDX
    CMP ECX, EDI
    JE fine
    ADD EDI, EDX
    JNO nooverflow2
    DEC EDI
    nooverflow2:
    CMP EAX, n
    JA over
    INC EAX
    JMP ciclo
    over:
      MOV EAX, -1
    fine:
  end;
End;
```

Answer (score -1):

This got me 100% in Javascript:

```
function solution(A) {
    if (!(A) || !(Array.isArray(A)) || A.length < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (A.length === 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    var sum = A.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }),
        lower = 0,
        i,
        val;

    for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        val = A[i];
        if (((sum - lower) - val) === (lower)) {
            return i;
        }
        lower += val;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[image: Equilibrium test results screenshot (Javascript)]

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer with with explanations on how to go about it. It will get you 100%

```
class Solution
{
    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        long sumLeft = 0;       //Variable to hold sum of elements to the left of the current index
        long sumRight = 0;      //Variable to hold sum of elements to the right of the current index
        long sum = 0;           //Variable to hold sum of all elements in the array
        long leftHolder = 0;    //Variable that holds the sum of all elements to the left of the current index, including the element accessed by the current index

        //Calculate the total sum of all elements in the array and store it in the sum variable
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            //sum = A.Sum();
            sum += A[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            //Calculate the sum of all elements before the current element plus the current element
            leftHolder += A[i];
            //Get the sum of all elements to the right of the current element
            sumRight = sum - leftHolder;
            //Get the sum of all elements of elements to the left of the current element.We don't include the current element in this sum
            sumLeft = sum - sumRight - A[i];
            //if the sum of the left elements is equal to the sum of the right elements. Return the index of the current element
            if (sumLeft == sumRight)
                return i;
        }
        //Otherwise return -1
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -2):

This may be old, but here is solution in Golang with 100% pass rate:

```
package solution

func Solution(A []int) int {
    // write your code in Go 1.4
    var left int64
    var right int64
    var equi int

    equi = -1
    if len(A) == 0 {
        return equi
    }

    left = 0
    for _, el := range A {
        right += int64(el)
    }

    for i, el := range A {
        right -= int64(el)
        if left == right {
            equi = i
        }
        left += int64(el)
    }

    return equi
}
```